# ROWID parameter in procedure

Tags: advantage-database-server

How do I set the datatype for a ROWID in an input or output parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROWID is a peudocolumn in SQL statements. It is a calculated fixed length character column with a size of 18.

More information is available in the [help file](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/master_rowid.htm).